UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bound in /build/linux-aws-6.5-Sh4SK5/linux-aws-6.5-6.5 .0/drivers/net/xen-netfront.c:824:4
I did an "apt-get dist-upgrade" and then rebooted, and my aws ec2 system is now effectively dead.
The console looks like:enter image description here
For the search engines, here is the text of the error:

UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bound in /build/linux-aws-6.5-Sh4SK5/linux-aws-6.5-6.5
.0/drivers/net/xen-netfront.c:824:4
index 138 is out of range for type 'xen_netif_tx_sring_entry [1]'

I just did an apt-get dist-upgrade, which seemed to work, and then rebooted.
The System Management Console is not working. I have not yet tried moving this to an Nitro type of EC2 instance, so I have not had a chance to try the serial console.
A few questions...
First, what did I do wrong, so I don't make this mistake again?
Second, how can I fix this problem. The AWS System Management web console isn't working. I have not tried switching to a nitro tyoe instance to get a serial console, yet. But, if that does work, how can I fix this driver issue?
This is Ubuntu 22.04 running on a t2.micro EC2 instance.
This actually has happened for two systems, as I was starting the regular patching cycle, and now I've got that on hold until I know more.
